# Writing to filehandle won't work with sleep

Tags: perl, while-loop, sleep, filehandle

I was working on a script when I suddenly realized I couldn't write to a file.

I've been able to get it down to this bit of code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $out, '>>', 'log.txt') or die "$!";
print $out "test";

while(1){
    sleep 1;
}
```

I tried taking off buffering by setting $| = 1.

I'm working on a program that runs and does something every 10 minutes, so I am using sleep to wait the 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you set `$|` to 1 while `$out` was selected, you didn't do anything.

If your perl is non-ancient, write

```
$out->autoflush(1);
```

If your perl is ancient, write

```
my $prev = select($out);
$| = 1;
select($prev);
```

Comment: thanks this worked (ancient version) ! Will accept in a couple of minutes. So $| only takes off buffering for stdout then? unless the new filehandle is selected?

Comment: In ancient times, `use IO::Handle; $out->autoflush(1);` works too; in even more ancient times, s/IO::Handle/FileHandle/

Comment: @ysth very true, but my memory isn't good enough to keep what works when straight, so I fall back to the 5.000 (or less) version :)

Comment: `$|` is one of several variables that just affect the currently selected or last input filehandle